# Convert a hashtable's keys to a list of strings

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, hashtable

I wanted to do `[string]::Join(", ", $HashTable.Keys);` but that returns `System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection...` instead of the enumerated values.

Do I need to make a foreach loop for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
$HashTable.Keys -join ','
```